# Multiple swift animations in parallel not working

Tags: ios, animation, swift

i have this code animating some elements (total of 3) in a view.

```
 for element in elements{          
        if element.value != radians {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.99,
                animations: {
                    element.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(radians))
                }, completion: {
                    finished in
                    element.value = radians
            })
        }
    }
```

When 2 or more elements should be animated (UIView.animateWithDuration is called 2 or more times one after another), only one is animating and the animation is quite choppy. I know that i should write everything in the animation block, but i can't figure out how to do it.
Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the for loop inside the animation block.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.99, 
  animations: {
    for element in elements {
      if element.value != radians {
          element.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(radians))
      }
    }
  }, completion: { _ in 
    element.value = radians
  })
```

Comment: i was thinking about this, but is it ok (safe)?

Comment: Indeed. Why should it not be? This is how it is done.

Comment: I thought that only assignments could be written in that block.